# Gulp ends too early when returning a promise instead of stream

Tags: node.js, gulp, tslint

I have a tslint task, when I return the gulp stream like this it works

```
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(tslint())
    .pipe(tslint.report('verbose'));
```

But when I try to return a promise instead it seems to finish before the task ends?

```
let deferred = Q.defer();
gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
  .pipe(tslint())
  .pipe(tslint.report('verbose'))
  .on('finish', () => deferred.resolve());
return deferred.promise;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fix this problem.

If you wish to return a Promise instead of just returning the stream, then  listen to the events `end` and `error`, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29722640/562978).

The second way is to switch from the [Q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q) library to [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) (or use the included Promise library in node).  I found that the Promise implementation in Q did not work as expected (using gulp 3.9.0 in node 4.2.6), but switching to bluebird did work.